# Django - [wsgi:error] [pid 16542:tid 140650901133056] Truncated or oversized response headers received from daemon process

Tags: django, apache, python-3.6, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I have googled and tried each and every option but nothing worked .
Below are the version specification which is used .
Apache/2.4.37 (AlmaLinux) OpenSSL/1.1.1k mod_wsgi/4.6.4 Python/3.6
and mariadb as the database
Using Virtual environment
Below are my Virtual Configuration paramters with wsgi

```
WSGIDaemonProcess cosmos processes=6 maximum-requests=300 header-buffer-size=65536 connect-timeout=30 python-path=/opt/cosmos/cosmos_api_v3:/opt/cosmos/cosmosenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
WSGIProcessGroup cosmos
WSGIScriptAlias /api /opt/cosmos/cosmos_api_v3/cosmos/wsgi.py
WSGIPassAuthorization On
```

Below are installed python packages

Package                       Version

---

amqp                          5.0.6
ansible                       2.9.0
asgiref                       3.4.1
bcrypt                        3.2.0
beautifulsoup4                4.11.2
billiard                      3.6.4.0
cached-property               1.5.2
celery                        5.1.2
certifi                       2021.5.30
cffi                          1.15.0
charset-normalizer            2.0.6
click                         7.1.2
click-didyoumean              0.3.0
click-plugins                 1.1.1
click-repl                    0.2.0
coreapi                       2.3.3
coreschema                    0.0.4
crypto                        1.4.1
cryptography                  35.0.0
Django                        3.2.7
django-auth-ldap              3.0.0
django-celery-beat            2.2.1
django-celery-results         2.2.0
django-cors-headers           3.10.0
django-filter                 21.1
django-rest-swagger           2.2.0
django-timezone-field         4.2.1
djangorestframework           3.12.4
djangorestframework-jwt       1.11.0
djangorestframework-simplejwt 4.4.0
docopt                        0.6.2
humanfriendly                 10.0
idna                          3.2
importlib-metadata            4.8.1
itypes                        1.2.0
Jinja2                        3.0.2
kombu                         5.1.0
lxml                          4.6.3
MarkupSafe                    2.0.1
mysql-connector               2.2.9
Naked                         0.1.31
openapi-codec                 1.3.2
packaging                     21.0
pandas                        1.1.5
paramiko                      2.8.0
pip                           21.3.1
prompt-toolkit                3.0.20
pyasn1                        0.4.8
pyasn1-modules                0.2.8
pycparser                     2.20
pycryptodome                  3.11.0
pyflakes                      2.3.1
Pygments                      2.10.0
PyJWT                         1.7.1
PyMySQL                       1.0.2
PyNaCl                        1.4.0
pyparsing                     3.0.2
python-crontab                2.5.1
python-dateutil               2.8.2
python-dotenv                 0.19.2
python-ldap                   3.3.1
python-magic                  0.4.27
pytz                          2021.1
pyvcloud                      23.0.3
pyvim                         3.0.2
pyvmomi                       7.0.2
PyYAML                        6.0
requests                      2.26.0
scp                           0.14.1
setuptools                    39.2.0
shellescape                   3.8.1
simplejson                    3.17.5
six                           1.16.0
soupsieve                     2.3.2.post1
sqlparse                      0.4.2
termcolor                     1.1.0
typing-extensions             3.10.0.2
unittest-xml-reporting        3.0.4
uritemplate                   4.0.0
urllib3                       1.26.7
vcd-api-schemas-type          10.3.0.dev72
vine                          5.0.0
wcwidth                       0.2.5
wheel                         0.37.0
zipp                          3.6.0